# Website not working well on IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have this website, http://www.escuelita.info. Now I tried many times to make it work on IE 7 (possibly IE6 too didn't check) but for some reason the middle frame on the right doesn't show content.

If you compare it to Firefox or Chrome (or even IE8) it works ok.
I need to fix this but I'm not sure what's causing the problem..

**Note**
I checked with IE7 and the pages don't show content
(the main content DIV `content_outer`)..

Comment: Try validating the html first, currently there are eight errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.escuelita.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content shows below the sidebar. Either IE7 enters quirks mode or you trigger some sort of bug that causes IE7 to misbehave.

Double check your doctype, tags and most importantly, get rid of those nested tables. Nested tables are EVIL and I'd bet they're your culprit. Use CSS grids (here's one that's really good: http://www.1kbgrid.com/) instead.

Dunno if this solves your problem, hopefully so.